# How to use ng-repeat with a JSON file stored in localStorage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, angularjs

I am learning how to save a JSON file (locally held) to the user's localStorage and then retrieve that information using Angular and use hg-repeat to put each object from the JSON file (consists of multiple objects representing products) into a product box (which shows up as search results)

Here is my Code so far..

**AJAX.JS**

```
if(typeof(Storage)!=="undefined")
{
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.searchButton').click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        timeout: 3000,
        url: "data/cars.json",
        dataType: "text",
        success: function(products) {

        alert(products);

        var dataToStore = JSON.stringify(products);
        localStorage.setItem('userData', dataToStore);
        alert(dataToStore);

        storedData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userData'));
        alert(storedData);

        window.location.href = "results.html";


        },

    });
    });
})
}
else {
alert("Sorry your browser is too old to support this website. Please update.");
}
```

**APP.JS**

```
var app = angular.module('searchFox', []);

app.controller('foxController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.valueFromLocalStorage = storedData;

}]);
```

HTML (SEARCH RESULTS PAGE // ANGULAR PART)

```
 <div class="row section">

        <div class="three columns" ng-repeat="v in valueFromLocalStorage">
            <div class="panel">
                <img class="panelImage" src="images/product6.jpg"></img>
                <p class="panelTitle">{{v.model}}</p>
                <p class="panelPrice">{{v.price}}</p>   
            </div>
            <img class="mFireOne"  src="images/fire.png">
            <p class="mViewOne">9318</p>
            <img class="mFireTwo"  src="images/heart.png">
            <p class="mViewTwo">172</p>
        </div>


    </div>
```

JSON FILE EXAMPLE

```
{
    "make": "honda",
    "model": "accord",
    "year": "1989",
    "mileage": "25000",
    "color": "black",
    "transmission": "automatic",
    "cylinders": "4",
    "type": "sedan",
    "title": "clean",
    "price": "$15,000",
    "img_url": "http://img.modifiedcartrader.com/uploaded/XL/2006/12/6584_Honda_Accord_1222200613708PM1.JPG"
},
{
    "make": "acura",
    "model": "integra",
    "year": "2001",
    "mileage": "108800",
    "color": "red",
    "transmission": "manual",
    "cylinders": "4",
    "type": "coupe",
    "title": "clean",
    "img_url": "http://carphotos.cardomain.com/ride_images/2/3951/4101/22377050003_large.jpg"
},
{
    "make": "ford",
    "model": "mustang",
    "year": "2015",
    "mileage": "1003",
    "color": "blue",
    "transmission": "manual",
    "cylinders": "8",
    "type": "coupe",
    "title": "clean",
    "img_url": "http://s1.cdn.autoevolution.com/images/news/gallery/2015-ford-mustang-rendered-with-slightly-different-face-rear-photo-gallery_6.jpg"
},
{
    "make": "volkswagen",
    "model": "golf",
    "year": "2002",
    "mileage": "86000",
    "color": "green",
    "transmission": "automatic",
    "cylinders": "4",
    "type": "hatchback",
    "title": "clean",
    "img_url": "http://zombdrive.com/images/2002_volkswagen_gti_2dr-hatchback_18t_s_oem_1_500.jpg"
},
{
    "make": "bmw",
    "model": "335i",
    "year": "2010",
    "mileage": "24664",
    "color": "red",
    "transmission": "manual",
    "cylinders": "6",
    "type": "sedan",
    "title": "clean",
    "img_url": "http://foodcourtlunch.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/03/bmw_335i_30.jpg"
}
```

]

So so far i'v managed to use AJAX to grab the locally help JSON file and save it to the user's localStorage. But now I cannot figure out how to correctly and cleanly send it over to the Angular Page (search results) and then to use hg-repeat to make a product container for every product object in the JSON file...

Comment: Iv added the JSON file as well!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need get your object from localstorage. You can use https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage this library as well.

example:

```

```
var app = angular.module('searchFox', ['LocalStorageModule']);

app.controller('foxController', ['$scope, LocalStorageModule', function($scope, LocalStorageModule) {
$scope.saved = "gold";
$scope.myObj = localStorageService.get('key')

}]);

<div class="three columns" ng-repeat="smth in myObj">
```

```

after that you will have your object in your view and can do with that everything you want.

Comment: How do i check on my side (developer side) if the local data is being saved? For example currently its setup to run the AJAX on click of the search button. Then the data "should" be said to be used by Angular on the next page (which shows the products organized)

Comment: You can use get method as well. for example: `$scope.myObj = localStorageService.get('key') || []`. If data wasn't saved you will get empty array in view. But i prefer use promise if i have async case somewhere.

Comment: Hey mate I am still having problems with this.. I am trying not to use the storage module you recommended. I also updated the original post code above so take a look if you can..for some reason hg-repeat isn't making a new component for each object in the array...thank you!

Comment: Hello. Can you print ur json object in ur html file {{ valueFromLocalStorage | json}} . Is it define?

Answer (score 0):

Eventually you want to feed ng-repeat an array.  Depending on your JSON file's contents you may have to call
`JSON.parse(jsonStr);`
or pass the contents of the object in JavaScript into an array somehow.

But think this:
`<div class="three columns" ng-repeat="??">`
Wants something like
`<div class="three columns" ng-repeat="{arrayOfObjects}">`
where is some `arrayOfObjects = [ {...}, {...}, {...}];`

Answer (score 0):

If you already have stored everything in `localStorage`, Angular can access the values directly using native JS or [angular-local-storage](https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage).

Just fetch values from `localStorage` in your controller, and pass it to view using `$scope`.

```
$scope.valueFromLocalStorage = window.localStorage.getItem('productQuery');
```

Now, you can use `ng-repeat` over `valueFromLocalStorage` to display values in your view.

```
 <div class="row section">

    <div class="three columns" ng-repeat="v in valueFromLocalStorage">
        <div class="panel">
            <img class="panelImage" ng-src="/images/{{v.imageName}}" ></img>
            <p class="panelTitle">{{v.name}}</p>
            <p class="panelPrice">{{v.price}}</p>   
        </div>
        <img class="mFireOne"  src="images/fire.png">
        <p class="mViewOne">9318</p>
        <img class="mFireTwo"  src="images/heart.png">
        <p class="mViewTwo">172</p>
    </div>
```

Also, there is a correction in your ajax.js file:

```
var save = function(obj) {
        localStorage["productQuery"] = JSON.stringify(obj); //obj instead of productQuery
};
```

Comment: Thanks for that correct! Also when I tried your version.. when the page loads its make like 500 + product modules..when there is only like 10 objects in a list in local storage. Im not sure why its repeating so many.. would you?

Comment: Oh the angular website said to put track by $index because I was getting errors.. is that why theres like 100's of products to many?

Comment: Share the `JSON` content which you store in `localStorage`.

Comment: Yes I have updated my question above with the JSON file contents

Comment: What do you think Aniket based on my JSON file above? I am still stuck with this problem and could use more of your help! Thank you!